# Keyboard layout *image* creator

Tags: images, keyboard-layout, snapshot

Is there a program for creating *images* of keyboard layouts? The program would be able to put a background image on each key but also provide its text. One could do it in Inkscape or such, but it would be nice to get rid any aligning problems, etc.

Comment: I wonder if you could use a graphical keyboard editor, then take a screenshot

Comment: @JourneymanGeek This does well for creating the initial layout and it is what I actually do. However this doesn't play terribly well with assigning *backgrounds* to the *individual* keys, one for each.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try [this online Keyboard Layout Editor](http://www.keyboard-layout-editor.com), where you can print your keyboard layout directly from your Web browser to a PDF/image file or just take screenshots therein.

Comment: the source code is available at github: https://github.com/ijprest/keyboard-layout-editor sunaku thanks for great advice! as a side note: please be careful in regarding a website as a 'program'. A website is a [software-as-a-service](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_as_a_service). the only guarantee that it will be available regardless of its curator is that it's open source and free software. You can read the so-called [franklin street statement](http://autonomo.us/2008/07/14/franklin-street-statement/) which provides guidelines on how to make a saas program open and free.